# Not able to load logging details to log file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging

In xyz file there will be having all .py files such as abcd.py efg.py etc which are to tested with logging.info instead print statements  I have set the configuration for logging.info as follows in the code
but messages are not loading into log file

for example

`logging.info('hi')`

'hi' is not been loading into the concerned log file

```
import logging.config

config={

    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {'default': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(module)s: %(message)s',
    }},
    'handlers': {'wsgi': {
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'stream': 'ext://flask.logging.wsgi_errors_stream',
        'formatter': 'default'
    },
    'fileHandler':{
        'class':'logging.handler.RotatingFileHandler',
        'formatter':'default',
        'filename':'log_info.log'
        'maxBytes':512000,
        'backupCount':5
    }},
    'root': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'handlers': ['wsgi']
    },
    'xyz':{
        'handler':['fileHandler'],
        'level':['info']
}}


logging.config.dictConfig(config)

log=logging.getLogger('root')
```

Comment: With respect, the grammar is very difficult to follow. Please consider revising the question to 1) add *clarity* to what is being asked, and 2) *ask* a specific question. Thank you.

Comment: could you review it once

Answer (score 0):

There was a quite a few small typos in your config that caused the missing logs, but annoyingly didn't raise any errors

1. Rotating file handler is located in `logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler`, notice the included "s" in "handlers"
2. Missing comma after `"filename"` key
3. Loggers have to be listed under their own nesting
4. Missing "s" in `"handlers"` key under logger configuration

Here's a sample in ended up with, I removed the flask part because I didn't have it installed

```
import logging
import logging.config

config={
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'default': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(module)s: %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'fileHandler': {
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'formatter':'default',
            'filename':'log_info.log',
            'maxBytes': 512000,
            'backupCount':5,
            "level": "INFO"
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        'xyz':{
            'handlers':['fileHandler'],
            'level': "INFO"
        }
    }
}

logging.config.dictConfig(config)

logger=logging.getLogger('xyz')
logger.info("moro")
```

Comment: Then in handler wsgi configuration is missing and there is no wsgi handler

Comment: You were missing with the above comment configurations

Comment: Can anyone pls do it with flask part

Comment: @dummy Just add what you had originally to the template I posted and it should work. If you have some problem with it, you should open a new question